# Babylonian Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to make a program that uses the Babylonian algorithm to compute the square root of a positive number **n** as follows :

1. Make a guess at the answer (you can pick n/2 as your initial guess).
2. Compute r = n / guess.
3. Set guess = (guess + r) / 2
4. Go back to step 2 until the last two guess values are within 1% of each other.

Now that's my code.

```
double n = input.nextDouble();
double guess = n / 2;

    while ()
    {
        double r = n / guess;
        guess = (guess + r) / 2;
        System.out.println(guess);

    }
```

How can I get the loop to stop iterating when guess is within 1% of the previous guess ? I don't get the part "guess is within 1% of the previous guess".

Comment: Keep track of the last guess using another variable and compute the % difference ((current-last)/last) * 100 and break when it's less than .01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
double n = input.nextDouble();
double guess = n / 2;

double pctDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double lastGuess = guess;

    while (Math.abs(pctDiff) >= 0.01)
    {                        
        double r = n / guess;
        guess = (guess + r) / 2;
        pctDiff = ((guess-lastGuess)/lastGuess); // normally, multiply by 100, but don't need to necessarily...
        lastGuess = guess;
        System.out.println(guess);

    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the percentage difference be (big number - small number) / big number ? In your code lastGuess is always the smaller.

Comment: doesn't matter, the result is computed as an absolute value. The formula as written provides a % change, which can be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous and the current guesses in separate variables. Then simply have an if statement to check how far your `currentGuess` is from `previousGuess`.

Comment: I'd definitely put the check in the condition of the while loop rather than in an if statement: while loops with no condition are rarely good.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm listed in the book [Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X) for square root with explanation 
added is

```
public static double sqrt(double c)
{
if (c < 0) return Double.NaN;// less than zero are complex numbers
double err = 1e-15; // (1 power -15)decreasing this will cause more accuracy 
                    // and more iterations to converge(quadratic 
                    // convergence) toward the actual value
double t = c; // initial positive value
while (Math.abs(t - c/t) > err * t)  
t = (c/t + t) / 2.0;
return t;
}
```