# Recursion/Babylonian method Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive code that calculates a square root.

I need to test my guess `(difference between x and guess*guess)`.

If the guess isn't accurate enough, you need to guess again.

And the new guess should be `= 0.5 * (lastGuess + x / lastGuess)`.

How do I get the user input to be assigned to `x` and then have `x` be sent to the squareRoot method to calculate the square root?

Also, I think I need a while loop to keep guessing until the answer is close enough?

Here is what I have right now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recursive
{
    public static void main(String []args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     double x;
     double error;

     System.out.println("Enter a number that you want the square root of");
     x = keyboard.nextDouble();

     double guess = x / 2;

     System.out.println("Enter an acceptable error");
     error = keyboard.nextDouble();

     System.out.println("The square root of " + x + " is " + squareRoot(x, guess, error));


  }

  public static double squareRoot(double x, double guess, double error)
  {
    double newGuess;

    if(Math.abs(guess * guess - x) <= error)
    {
      return guess;
    }
    else
    {
      newGuess = 0.5 * (guess + (x / guess));
     return newGuess;

    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will first need some other variables to be defined, these are your guess and error variables.

```
System.out.println("Enter your guess of the square root");
guess = keyboard.nextDouble();
error = 0.5D
```

To pass your users input 'x' to the square root method, you can simply call it like such

```
squareRoot = squareRoot(x, guess, error)
```

Comment: Apparently the code will end up using the squareRoot variable to hold the square root after the recursion but that isn't very clear from what the OP says.

Comment: I see now, the variables assigned in the main method don't seem nessecary. The recursive fucnctions structure is probably adding confusion OP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function from main the first time to start the recursion.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         double x;
         double guess = 1.0; //initialized double
         double error = 1.0; //initialized double
         double squareRoot; <-- is this to hold the final sqrt?

         System.out.println("Enter a number you want to find the square root of.");
         x = keyboard.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Make a guess as to what the square root is.");
         guess = keyboard.nextDouble(); //get the guess here

         squareRoot = squareRoot(x, guess, error); //Call your function here
         System.out.println("The answer is: " + x);
     }
```

Your requirements are too vague to help you much more without just guessing at what you're trying to do. Fix these things and see where you are, try to solve it with this knowledge and the problem specs, and, if necessary, ask something more specific and clear and I'll try to help more.

Comment: The code needs to find the square root of x, guess the square root is x / 2. Test the guess, difference between x -  guess * guess. If the guess isn't accurate enough, try again. The new guess should be 0.5 * (last guess + x / last guess)

Updated: https://gist.github.com/xyuzuki/ff514b99e23cf735eba1e83f699eeeb6

Comment: 1) The square root of x is not x / 2. For example, the square root of 49 is 7. 49 / 2 = 24.5. 
2) What if the new guess isn't 0.5 * (last guess + x / last guess)? This part makes exactly no sense at all. A person can guess anything they want to guess. I could guess 24.5 for the square root of 49 and when your program told me to try again I could guess 24.3. How can I know what to guess if it should be 0.5 * (last guess + x / last guess) ?

Comment: Wait I'm sorry. I mean I need a loop, for the newGuess to go several times until the answer is within an acceptable error. So like currently it if I enter 1 and a 0.01 acceptable error range, 1.25 would come out. But it is suppose to loop until it is very close.

Comment: Then the recursion is only to determine the real square root. You need another method to continue to prompt the user for a number. Your logic should go like this: 
Step 1: Ask the user for the number ::: Step 2: Find the actual square root of the number and store it ::: Step 3: Ask the user to guess ::: Step 4: Check the guess against the true square root ::: Step 5: If the guess is within the tolerance then return the guess. If not then continue to prompt the user. You will need main and two other methods. One of them will find the real square root and the other will test each guess.

Comment: If you write these methods and have specific questions then please post the code you have here and ask the questions.

Comment: How do I make the if recursive?

Comment: You need to follow the steps I gave you. That function is totally wrong for what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to combine the method which calculates the true square root with the method that will test if it's correct. If I'm wrong then explain how you think it needs to work.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is one way of doing it, and the other way is using a loop.

When you are using recursion, the exit criteria takes care of the precision. You do not need to maintain any other loop.

```
if(error <= ((guess * guess) - x))
{
  return guess;
}
```

The other way is using a loop instead of recursion. Refer this link for loop based solution: [Babylonian Algorithm in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092196/babylonian-algorithm-in-java).
In this case, the precision (variable `error` as per your code sample) goes in the loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the user input to be assigned to x?

The line `x = keyboard.nextDouble();` assigns the user input to the local variable `x`. This variable only exists in `main()`, and is different from the parameter `x` in `squareRoot(double x, double guess, double error)`.

> How do I send x to the squareRoot method to calculate the square root?

You need to make a call to `squareRoot` and pass local `x` to parameter `x`. You also need to pass something non-zero to parameters `guess` and `error`. Local `x` could be a valid `guess`, and `.05` could be a valid `error`.

```
double result = squareRoot(x, x, .05);
```

If you don't call `squareRoot` in you main function, `squareRoot` will never be run.

> Also, I think I need a while loop to keep guessing until the answer is close enough?

You need a loop of some sort, but the code you provided has a recursive loop. The function `squareRoot` has a call to itself, but there are some problems.

First, the recursive call is `squareRoot(x, guess, error)` but needs to be `squareRoot(x, newGuess, error)`. The current version will test the same guess over and over again, when what you want to do is test the newGuess.

Secondly, `if(error <= ((guess * guess) - x))` is wrong. It will end the loop if the actual error is greater than the target error, but you want to end if the actual error is smaller than the target error. Reverse the comparison operator, and also take the absolute value of ((guess * guess) - x). You don't want a tiny guess to result in a negative error. Error values should always be positive.

Comment: The code needs to find the square root of x, guess the square root is x / 2. Test the guess, difference between x -  guess * guess. If the guess isn't accurate enough, try again. The new guess should be 0.5 * (last guess + x / last guess)
Sorry for not being clear

Updated:  https://gist.github.com/xyuzuki/ff514b99e23cf735eba1e83f699eeeb6